# Index exact word matching, when no match result "" instead of 0?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How would one change this formula to return "" instead of 0 if there is no match?

=INDEX(Table2[Category],MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Table2[Keyword],[@Description])),0))

Regards,

Jonas Blazinskas

Comment: Does this formula return `""` in the first place? How? Just include an `IFERROR`, see the construct above ^^

Comment: No it does not it returns a 0, but instead of a zero I want it to return either an error or ""

Comment: If it is returning 0, then it found a match but category is empty.  You can do: `=INDEX(Table2[Category],MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Table2[Keyword],[@Description])),0))&""`

Comment: Why not =If((your formula above)= 0, char (34)&char(34),(your formula above)) or do ="0"  if needed.